# Set operations in batch files

Tags: batch-file, set

I have two files and want to check whether one 'contains' the other in a batch script. By 'contains' I mean that the SET of lines in the first file contains the SET of lines in the second file.

For example this file:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

contains this file:

```
a
b
d
g
```

but does not contain this file:

```
a
b
z
```

I realize that the task is not very complex but I wonder whether there exists a command line tool that supports set-like operations out of the box. For example, as an alternative for writing a for loop that searches each line from the second file in the first file...

Comment: Batch files often rely on context in the files, character sets used, and need special processing if poison characters exist.  Your example shows nothing about the actual task or makeup of the files.

Comment: In other words, please give us a few, more detailed examples of your situation. Also provide the code you have tried so far

Comment: @foxidrive, I did not mention these because there is no concern here. Files are ascii encoded.

Comment: @Monacraft, the examples are as simple as they appear. I did not try anything for now because I am looking for the best tool for the job. I know how to do this with Java/C#, but I want to do this in a scripting language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** most of the code in the original post is not needed, so ...

With your set of files, named (in the same order) `fullList.txt`, `list1.txt` and `list2.txt`, this should work

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "mainFile=.\fullList.txt"

    for %%f in (list*.txt) do (
        findstr /l /x /v /g:"%mainFile%" "%%~ff" >nul && ( 
            echo %%f is not included 
        ) || ( 
            echo %%f is included 
        )
    )
```

How does it work? It is just a `findstr` command for each file. It searchs the "small list" file for strings not contained in the "big list" file. If any line is found, the file is not contained, else it is contained

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
SET "is_subset=Y"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (subset_file.txt) DO (
 FIND "%%a" "superset_file.txt">NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO fail ON "%%a"&SET "is_subset=N"&GOTO done
)
:done
POPD
ECHO subset IN superset : %is_subset%

GOTO :EOF
```

This should work - but your question is unclear. This will check that the superset contains **every** member of the subset, but you may be searching for **some** members.

I used test files on my `U:` drive - you would need to modify to suit.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below solve the problem in a very fast way. As additional data, it show the lines from the small file not contained in the large file:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "delims=" %%a in (smallFile.txt) do set "line[%%a]=1"
for /F "delims=" %%a in (largeFile.txt) do set "line[%%a]="
set "anyLine="
for /F %%a in ('set line[ 2^>NUL') do set "anyLine=1"
if defined anyLine (
   echo Large file does NOT "contain" the small file. Lines not contained:
   echo/
   for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('set line[') do echo %%a
) else (
   echo Large file "contain" the small file.
)
```